# Aerospike AQL How to calculate sum of records in stream

Tags: aerospike

How do I calculate the sum of values with `where` clause in `Aerospike`.
I am a newbie in `Aerospike`. Any good reference documentations that I could follow?

Answer (score 3):

Either aggregate in client as records are returned in callback from Secondary Index query or use a Stream UDF.

You can use the Stream UDF approach with AQL.  But, you should really write a standalone application using one of the clients, such as the Java client.

Using Java Client: 
For SI query approach see code example here:  https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/examples/application/queries.html

For Stream UDF approach, see code example here: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/examples/application/aggregate.html

Comment: Nice info, Thanks!

Comment: These documents are referring to count but I want to do the sum of bin values. Like RDMS querying how can I do aql query in Aerospike.

Comment: You can sum the bin values. You get to write the Stream UDF function. You can do whatever aggregation, filtering etc you want in the function. Look in the section on developing Stream UDFs.